# run a task in only ONE pod (of multiple pods)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

I am trying to run a process in only ONE docker pod (and not the other n pods),

can I know (from inside a pod/instance)

- am I the first pod?
- how many pods are running?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. Put that thing in its own deployment (or statefulset more likely) that is unrelated to the others.

Comment: this seems to be the team consensus. though i'm unclear on why it's bad practice.

Comment: Because the definition of pod replicas is that they are identical and interchangeable (technical term: “fungible”).