# How to make sure that the script is run from only one of the PODs of all replicas?

Tags: kubernetes

Our product is running on Kubernetes/Docker.

I have a POD which will be running multiple replicas. There is a script in the POD which will be run after POD start. The script needs the main process in the POD to be running.

The problem is the script should be run only from one POD. With multiple replicas the script will be run multiple times.
How to make sure that the script is run from only one of the PODs of all replicas?
Thanks
Chandra

Comment: Does this answer your question? [run a task in only ONE pod (of multiple pods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61090273/run-a-task-in-only-one-pod-of-multiple-pods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using helm, helm post install hook can be used.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to run script from only one replica of a pod. Use cronjob for such usecase.

Comment: The problem is that script needs a process in the POD to be up an running. If I put the script in cronjob, it might start even before the POD.